# Group lines in a file and feed a group to a program at a time

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a program which takes urls as commandline arguments and output a pdf file. For example, I use command substitution to provide the input urls from a file `urlsfile`

```
wkhtmltopdf $(cat urlsfile) my.pdf
```

In `urlsfile`, each line is a url.

Now I would like to group every 15 lines in `urlsfile`, and feed a group of urls to the program at a time.
How can I do that in bash?

Note that it is acceptable to create a pdf file per 15 urls, and then I will merge the pdf files into one. If the merge can be done by the program, that is better.

Thanks.

Comment: `cat urlsfile | xargs wkhtmltopdf my.pdf`  doesn't work, because I only know the program takes inputs from cmdline args, and not sure how to make it take inputs from stdin.

Comment: For this particular application, the online documentation suggests that `wkhtmltopdf` provides a `--read-args-from-stdin` option that may be useful

Answer (score 4):

With `xargs`:

`xargs -a urlsfile -n 15 bash -c 'wkhtmltopdf "$@" my_$$.pdf'`

or if your `xargs` doesn't support `-a`:

`cat urlsfile | xargs -n 15 bash -c 'wkhtmltopdf "$@" my_$$.pdf'`

Comment: Thanks. What does `$* my_$$.pdf` mean?

Comment: thanks @ilkkachu `"$@"` is the right one

Comment: Cool (+1)  xargs is always a source of surprises for me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
gawk        '{ f=f " " $0} 
    NR%15==0 { print("wrhtml2pdf " f " " NR/15 ".pdf") ; f=""}' urls
```

and if you like the output, replace `print` by `system`